# Jersey Client singleton vs Multiple Jersey Client insantiations

Tags: java, jersey

I'm working on a servlet app, and I'm using Jersey to act as a client. I've read in several places that it's better to instantiate a single Client and use it throughout the application's life than instantiating and destroying multiple clients, especially since creating a client is quite expensive. The thing is that the Client's role in this app is very, VERY simple. It's just a get, and that's it. And the data is a json object with 3 String values. Super easy. And this makes me think if even in this scenario is justifiable using a single Client instantiation. What would be better: a single instance, or multiple instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think it does not matter if the client would execute only `GET` methods or any other methods like `POST`, `PUT`, etc. As long as you initialize a client before each call; you'll eventually be spending resources for nothing...

Comment: So it makes sense to use a singleton for the client, then?